# How would I search an IDA pro database for instances of I.P addresses?

Tags: ida, disassembly

Simple as that. I have a massive Disassembly, that I want to check for I.P addresses. Since the text search in IDA doesn't seem to have a regex function, I'm not sure the best way to get this done. Perhaps a script?

I also realize this may be complicated by the fact that some of the I.P adresses may not exist as strings.

Comment: Are these specific IP addresses you know, or are you looking for anything that looks like a random IP address?

Comment: Anything that looks like a random i.p address

Comment: You'll never find random IP addresses that aren't strings that way, since just about every byte combination might be an IP address. Or better, you'll find way too many. Even your "Hello world!" string might be 110.145.154.154 .. As for strings, right-clicking the strings window and selecting "modify filters" brings up a dialog that includes a "regular expression" checkbox.

Comment: That's a useful answer, thanks! I would have expected a regex search to have been under the text search functionality.

Comment: However, if you have any tips for automatically finding spots where I.P addresses that *aren't* strings are loaded into memory (I'm trying to find the "call home" i.p for an antivirus) I'm all ears.

Comment: Why don't you just run the software and use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to trace the network? Or, if you don't want to run the software on your computer, or don't want the "call home" probes to reach "home", set up a virtualbox with "host only" networking and [trace the guest network](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Network_tips).

Comment: Well, in this case what I have is a port that listens for something, most likely IP filtered. Only responds to ping probes from arbitrary hosts, but I'm trying to figure out if it listens from the home server. I can't necessarily force the server to speak to the client in this case.

Comment: Any reason we are Downvoting an ancient question? This is an on topic question.

Answer (score 1):

> Only responds to ping probes from arbitrary hosts

In that case, reverse engineer the code that calls [`recvfrom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out how it validates the source IP of the received ping packet.